# Disable the "always on top" option. IBM Notes 9

Tags: email, lotus-notes, always-on-top

How do I disable the "always on top" windows option on Notes 9

I've looked everywhere for an answer and haven't been able to find one. Looked under the view tab but there is no opt-in option to disable this feature.
I am unable to bring another window to the top.

How can I disable this?

Comment: Are you saying that the entire Notes client is sitting in foreground, preventing you from switching to any other window? That sounds more like you're encountering a bug rather than missing an  option setting.

Comment: I have this happen in 8 sometimes, pretty sure it's a bug. Minimizing Notes and then switching to the other app seems to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Found on IBM Sametime forum, [RE: How to prevent chat window popup always on top](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/stforum.nsf/0/76ba11204e48544485257be40074025d?OpenDocument), (and works):

1. In Lotus Notes select File > Preferences
2. Expand Sametime
3. Select Notifications
4. Select the One-on-one chat Event
5. Clear the Bring chat window to front option
6. Click OK

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too and I just recently found out how to disable it.
If you have Sametime embedded in your notes 9, please go to Settings>View and uncheck "Always On Top".

Answer (score 1):

Right Click the title bar of Lotus Notes, de-select 'Always on Top' checkbox.